# Creating nested dictionary in python from multiple data sources

Tags: python, dictionary, networking, nested

Rewording this entirely as the original post wasn't clear.  What I'm trying to do is parse through some data line by line and create a dictionary.  I'm thinking there is a better way to organize this data.  The original way I was trying to go about this didn't account for several things so I came up with this. I'm looping through service policy output line by line to put together the data by Interface, policy name, and then pulling out the queue, drops, and no-buffer drops.  The problem I'm having is it's not accounting for the extra policy so the original pass of data gets overwritten.

Service Policy Output:

```
GigabitEthernet11/1

Service-policy output: Gi11_1

Counters last updated 7191104 seconds ago

Class-map: class-default (match-any)
  0 packets, 0 bytes
  30 second offered rate 0000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
  Match: any 
  Queueing
  queue limit 33025 packets
  (queue depth/total drops/no-buffer drops) 0/0/0
  (pkts output/bytes output) 0/0
  shape (average) cir 500000000, bc 2000000, be 2000000
  target shape rate 500000000

  Service-policy : child

  Counters last updated 7191104 seconds ago

    Class-map: class-default (match-any)
      0 packets, 0 bytes
      30 second offered rate 0000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
      Match: any 
      Queueing
      queue limit 33025 packets
      (queue depth/total drops/no-buffer drops) 0/0/0
      (pkts output/bytes output) 0/0
      bandwidth remaining ratio 100 

for ints, int_strings in zip(int_names, int_output):
    counts.setdefault(ints, {})

    for line in int_strings.splitlines():
        matchpolicy = re.search(r'(Service-policy.*)', line)
        matchdrops = re.findall(r'total drops.*', line)
        if matchpolicy:
            spolicies = matchpolicy.group(0)
            counts[ints]['Policy'] = spolicies
        if matchdrops:
            regx = re.search(r'\s(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)', line)
            counts[ints]['queue'] = int(regx.group(1))
            counts[ints]['drops'] = int(regx.group(2))
            counts[ints]['no-buffer'] = int(regx.group(3))

return counts
```

I tried creating a dictionary with an additional depth level,  but I'm getting a key error on the counts[ints][spolicies] line.  From what I read I thought this was how nested dictionaries worked but I'm thinking I misunderstood.

```
for ints, int_strings in zip(int_names, int_output):
    counts.setdefault(ints, {})

    for line in int_strings.splitlines():
        matchpolicy = re.search(r'(Service-policy.*)', line)
        matchdrops = re.findall(r'total drops.*', line)
        if matchpolicy:
            spolicies = matchpolicy.group(0)
            counts[ints][spolicies] 
        if matchdrops:
            regx = re.search(r'\s(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)', line)
            counts[ints][spolicies]['queue'] = int(regx.group(1))
            counts[ints][spolicies]['drops'] = int(regx.group(2))
            counts[ints][spolicies]['no-buffer'] = int(regx.group(3))

return counts
```

Either way, I'm assuming there may be a better way to organize this data so I Can go through it easier later.  Any ideas?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
labels = ["depth", "drops", "buffer_drops"]
values = ['0', '14996', '0', '0', '2100', '0']
keys=['Gi1','Gi2']

values_grouped_by_3 = list(zip(*[iter(values)]*3))
data = dict(zip(keys,[dict(zip(labels,vals)) for vals in values_grouped_by_3]))
```

if you would like more of a tutorial and actual help then please make an effort first and post your effort and what you expected and what your output is

Comment: Apologies, all the code I was coming up with didn't make any sense so I didn't want to cloud the post with it.  I changed my code so many times at this point I'm not even sure where I started.  I had something along the lines of:  #for interface_strings, header_strings in header_strings:
    # intf[header_strings][interface_strings].append(outerrs)  (I realize that didn't post correctly at all)